# Chrome on Yosemite

Tags: google-chrome

I had a number of application warn me that Snow Leopard is no longer supported, so I've updated my main system to Yosemite. (I am on a 2010 Mac Pro, BTW)

Now, Chrome is acting strangely, for a number of sites that have an embedded image I get

[image]

That's what I see on [Wolfram Alpha](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/BuyOrRentInvestmentReturnCalculator/) among other sites. It might go away for a time after restarting Chrome, but it always returns. Any idea what this is, and the fix?

Comment: Do you have an Apple GPU or aftermarket? Also, is Chrome up to date?

Comment: NVIDIA GeForce GT 120 - (This is aftermarket, right?) My other 2010 Pro has The ATI Radeon. Yes, Chrome is up to date.

Comment: GT 120 should be the original, from that period. Monomeeth seems to have got it though..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of possible causes for this, but the first thing I would try is turning off hardware acceleration in Google Chrome. To do this, follow these steps:

1. Launch Google Chrome
2. Go to Chrome > Preferences (or just press the <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>,</kbd> keyboard shortcut
3. At the bottom of the page, click on *Show advanced settings...*
4. Look for the **System** subheading in the new settings that appear
5. Uncheck the *Use hardware acceleration when available* option
6. Restart Google Chrome

Let us know how you go.

Comment: So far, that's it. Idiot-proof directions above (thanks) and a restart, now that mess is gone. I'll mark as 'accepted' if still gone in 24 hrs. Thanks!